# Visual Studio 2010: Name of document tab context menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know the name of the context menu that you get when right clicking a document tab in Visual Studio 2010?

I want to add the "Close All Documents" command to it, but I cannot figure out which context menu it is in the customize dialog.

Comment: Good question. [Tabs Studio](http://www.tabsstudio.com/) gives the "Close All Documents" command, so I've never had to worry about it ;)

Comment: You could also map `CTRL+ALT+F4` in Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard, Command name Windows.CloseAllDocuments (Actually I think this is already mapped in VS2010 to `Alt+ W, L`)

Comment: I need to know the exact name because I'm creating a visual studio extension that will add a command inside that menu. I already added a command in the item node context menu using IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can find that menu at [**Other Context Menus | Easy MDI Document Window**](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/VisualStudio2010AddAnExtraContextMenuItemToTheDocumentTab.aspx).

Comment: Just for future reference, the full name in the customize list is "Other Context Menus | Easy MDI Document Window".

Comment: Thanks Preston. I've updated my answer to include the **Other Context Menus** part.

Comment: Note, in Visual Studio 2010 to add a command to the right-click menu of a document’s tab, first you’ll need to right-click on a Visual Studio document tab to work around a Visual Studio bug. (Otherwise the Easy MDI Document Window context menu doesn’t show up in the Customize dialog.)                                 [Source](http://blog.tabsstudio.com/2011/03/24/tab-context-menu-commands-from-other-visual-studio-add-ins/)

Comment: This had been driving me crazy all day - insane that they gave such a terrible unintuitive name to such an important context menu. Note: this is still the name of it in Visual Studio 2017 (and presumably all the versions in between.)

Comment: FYI, in 2017 its almost halfway down the huge list of context menus. When you get to the end of `Other Context Menus | Code Window | ...` choices, its about 20 more down. (Unfortunate that there is no way to sort these alphabetically, nor a search function to filter the list.)